# Footer not showing at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

So today, while building my html blade template, i realized that my footer, does not show at the bottom of the page. It instead shows at like the middle of the page.

These are my codes;

`app.blade.php` (my "template" basically)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#fdb918">
    <link rel="manifest" href="{{asset('manifest.json')}}">
    @include('layouts.scripts.mainscripts')
    @include('layouts.styles.styles')
    @include('layouts.scripts.social-login')
    {!! SEO::generate() !!}
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <header>
            @include('layouts.header.header')
        </header>
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
        <footer>
            @include('layouts.footer.footer')
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
@include('layouts.scripts.scripts')


</html>
```

my `footer.blade.php`

```
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="footer-container">
        <div class="footer bg-faded">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row footer-top flex-md-row no-gutters">

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-12 float-sm-left hidden-sm-down">
                        <small>All rights reserved</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-12 float-sm-right kor_ipad">
                        <h3>Contact</h3>
                        <div class="block-help-text">
                            <div class="help-content">
                                <a href="mailto:help.my@.com">help.my@.com</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block-help-text">
                            <div class="help-content">
                                <a href="tel:+">+</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-12 float-sm-left hidden-md-up">
                        <div class="folow-us social-link-inner-mobile">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com//" target="_blank">
                                <i class="icon-social icon-facebook" title="Facebook Logo | "></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com//" target="_blank">
                                <i class="icon-social icon-instagram" title="Instagram Logo | "></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/" target="_blank">
                                <i class="icon-social icon-youtube" title="YouTube Logo | "></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <small>All rights reserved</small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="footer-bottom">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                            <div class="group-link">
                                <a href="/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a>
                                <a href="/terms-conditions">Terms & Conditions</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-md-8 hidden-sm-down no-pd-left">
                            <div class="folow-us social-link-inner">
                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com//" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="icon-social icon-facebook" title="Facebook Logo | "></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="https://www.instagram.com//" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="icon-social icon-instagram" title="Instagram Logo | "></i>
                                </a>

                                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4Hd_9mBGxhD6PRNy9scHqQ/featured" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="icon-social icon-youtube" title="YouTube Logo | "></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Is there a reason as to why my footer shows at the middle of the page instead of the bottom of the page? Also, another thing i noticed is that my footers position is absolute, like no matter where i call it, it's always in the same location.

Comment: If you `inspect element` in browser...what is the footer content position there?

Comment: it shows that the footer is indeed at the bottom of all the other lines of codes (bar any jquery related stuff). that's why it's a bit odd. cause even though in inspect element, it shows it at the bottom, it still shows up in the middle of the page.

Comment: make `app.blade.php > <footer>` position as `relative`

Comment: let me know if it's still not working.

Comment: it works fine now, was taking some time to set it. but are you sure setting as relative is a good idea?

Comment: added the explanation in solution.

Answer (score 0):

make `app.blade.php` > `<footer>` position as `relative` Like:

```
<footer style="position:relative;">
     @include('layouts.footer.footer')
</footer>
```

You can also use the external style here :)

You would like to place the element at bottom (after ) and in your `footer.blade.php` > `<footer id="footer">` position given as `absolute` so it's displaying related to the other element in `<body>`.

If you define `relative` position to `app.blade.php`> `<footer>`, other absolute element contains inside it would be related or mapped from this element `<footer>`.

Hopefully! this helps to understand the issue.

Comment: One more thing, you should change the `footer.blade.php` > `<footer>` element with `<div>` because you have already used `<footer>` inside `app.blade.php`.

Comment: Let me know if you still having any concern.